# Cannot connect to the Internet on Lenovo Ideapad Z580.

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, lenovo

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 7 on a Lenovo Ideapad Z580.
I have been having problems recently in connecting to the Internet since I've switched to a new router namely Edimax AR-7286WnA.
Now, I can connect to the Internet using the same router connection absolutely well on Windows 7, whereas such has not been my fate in Ubuntu. The problem even though small, becomes even more frustrating when I connect Ubuntu to my mobile phone's hotspot and even then it doesn't work.

Ubuntu easily connects to both the connections but when I try to browse any page on Mozilla Firefox, it just keeps on loading for a while and then gives up!

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3975]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0587]
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Wifi diagnostic script result: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10132109/

*I am an absolute newbie to Ubuntu and thus would need a descriptive help and solution to this problem.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20971/discussion-on-question-by-apurv-vashisht-cannot-connect-to-the-internet-on-lenov).

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was a bad nameserver in resolv.conf that was fixed with

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`

Comment: I can't run this script as there is no way I can access internet on Ubuntu. Please help me out here!

Comment: Can you make a temporary wired connection to the router while downloading and installing those packages?

Comment: I've tried doing that, but it's not helping me either.

Comment: No need. It looks like this is not a driver issue according to what me just told you in the question comments.

Answer (score 0):

The DNS server you have configured doesn't respond. You should really let your router configure this stuff through the DHCP protocol, unless you know what you're doing.

- Check in the network connection settings under the IPv4 tab that the method is set to *Automatically (DHCP)*.
- Alternatively, check that the NetworkManager Wifi connection configuration file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` has the entry `method=auto` in the `[ipv4]` section.

If for some weird reason it's already set to automatic and the router announces itself as the default DNS server, even though it doesn't actually run a DNS service,

1. check your router configuration and restart it. Sometimes individual services on routers stop working but a reboot brings them back to life.
2. If nothing else helps, configure Ubuntu to use a different DNS server:

   In the connection settings under *Additional DNS servers* enter one or more known good DNS server IP addresses (comma-separated), e. g. those of your ISP. Otherwise Google's are quite reliable, if you don't mind the possible privacy implications. Beyond that there are [public DNS server lists](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/a/free-public-dns-servers.htm). Example (with Google servers):

   ```
   8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
   ```

Comment: Yes it is set to automatic.

Comment: Weird. See my update.

Comment: Well I've tries doing both the solutions in your updated answer, but somehow that doesn't seem to help me either.

Comment: Let's see how Jeremy's hunch about `resolv.conf` turns out.